# как я могу вместо верстки отобразить json как будто это апи

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, компоненты, next.js

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next"
import { FC } from "react"

const App: FC = (props: any) => {
 
  return (props)
}

export default App


export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const props = await {
    test: 'Test'
  }
  return await {props}
}
```

можно ли вывести вместо **HTML** джейсон обект *Content-Type* *application/json* ?
и можно ли *кастомизировать* рендер **компонента** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отобразить JSON в html можно очень простым нативным способом. Для этого нужно просто обернуть результат выполнения `JSON.stringify()` в тег `<pre>` и получится неплохой результат:

```
import data from "./data.json";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на песочницу react](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-proskuriakova-ngurt1?file=/src/App.js)

UPD:

Если нативное самописное решение не устраивает и хочется уже готовый пакет использовать, то можно воспользоваться библиотечкой [react-json-view](https://github.com/mac-s-g/react-json-view)

```
import ReactJson from "react-json-view";
import data from "./data.json";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactJson src={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на песочницу с react-json-view](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-bird-zk1gwe?file=/src/App.js)